# Receber um array de objetos num controlador php

Tags: angularjs, laravel

Eu quero enviar um `array` de objetos para o meu controlador `PHP` e tenho feito desta maneira

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: "payment/pagamento",
    data: $.param(vm.listProdsCar),
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).success(function(response) {
        console.log(response);   

    }).error(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
```

O meu array `vm.listProdsCar` é assim:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

agora eu queria receber este `array` no `PHP` `controller` tipo isto:

```
public function postPayment(Request $request)
    {

foreach($request->all as $req){
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("'$req->name'");</script>';
  }
    }
```

Mas nada disto está a funcionar, alguma sujestão?

Comment: já tentou colocar `var_dump($request->all());` para ver o que imprime?